# context.df.isReplaying is always undefined

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I’m trying to build an Azure durable function in TypeScript using the programming model v4.
Sadly during my tests I noticed that every *context.log* is logged multiple times.

After digging in, I’ve learned that it’s one of the weirdest things in the Durable functions.
However based on [Azure documentation about App Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=javascript), I should be able to resolve this  issue by simply checking if the *context.df.isReplaying* is **false**. eg:

```
if (!context.df.isReplaying) context.log("Calling F1.");
```

Believe me or not but this is not working.
Every single time I’m getting that *context.df.isReplaying* is **undefined**.

After few experiments I’m able to get the correct value for *isReplaying* but from *context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying*.
I started thinking that there should be something wrong with how I implemented my durable functions, however even the [durable functions starter from Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-ts-vscode?pivots=nodejs-model-v4) is giving me the same result (check attached screenshot)

[image]

1. Is this a bug in the Azure programming model v4 or their documentation is not updated?
2. Do you think I could rely on context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying?

I'm using node: **18.9.0** and durable-functions: **3.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=csharp-inproc#app-logging), `Context.df.IsReplaying` seems to be supporting only in ***Javascript but not in Typescript*** Azure functions.

- I have created both **JavaScript** and **Typescript** `Azure durable functions` to check the same.

**durableHello.Js:**

```js
const activityName = 'durableHello';

df.app.orchestration('durableHelloOrchestrator', function* (context) {
    const outputs = [];

    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Tokyo'));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Seattle'));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Cairo'));
    context.log('---------------context.isReplaying-------------', context.df.isReplaying);
    context.log('----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying---------------', context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying);
    context.log('*******************************');
    return outputs;
});
```

**Console Output:**

I could see `context.df.isReplaying` executing once with an exact value.

```js
C:\Users\username\nodejsfn>func host start

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-27T13:25:50.267Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

       durableHelloHttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/{orchestratorName}

       durableHello: activityTrigger

       durableHelloOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-27T13:25:55.184Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2023-12-27T13:26:06.681Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloHttpStart' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=07ac1753-296c-4705-8577-54066a43b31d)
[2023-12-27T13:26:07.422Z] Started orchestration with ID = '00a96c94666441c6a8f155fe170a8ae1'.
[2023-12-27T13:26:07.617Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=d4917c85-86ae-44d9-a609-494397848fd1)
[2023-12-27T13:26:07.734Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloHttpStart' (Succeeded, Id=07ac1753-296c-4705-8577-54066a43b31d, Duration=1122ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:07.738Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=d4917c85-86ae-44d9-a609-494397848fd1, Duration=133ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:07.914Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=423b07b2-6121-4e30-bff0-2047ce1f3ecb)
[2023-12-27T13:26:07.921Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHello' (Succeeded, Id=423b07b2-6121-4e30-bff0-2047ce1f3ecb, Duration=10ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.015Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=ecc7c503-c2f2-4a58-96dd-4ba768fd9cbd)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.036Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=ecc7c503-c2f2-4a58-96dd-4ba768fd9cbd, Duration=24ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.100Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=2e629772-6b99-44e2-8a26-436de083fe6b)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.107Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHello' (Succeeded, Id=2e629772-6b99-44e2-8a26-436de083fe6b, Duration=8ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.162Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=7a7e68ab-3d21-4959-bc2b-0f7160dc794d)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.174Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=7a7e68ab-3d21-4959-bc2b-0f7160dc794d, Duration=12ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.227Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=89a66351-de1f-402d-9b6a-8e53e0244dc8)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.235Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHello' (Succeeded, Id=89a66351-de1f-402d-9b6a-8e53e0244dc8, Duration=8ms)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.297Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=32978907-2431-43ea-a4cc-46ad6508f796)
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.308Z] ----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying--------------- True       
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.308Z] ---------------context.isReplaying------------- false
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.308Z] *******************************
[2023-12-27T13:26:08.322Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=32978907-2431-43ea-a4cc-46ad6508f796, Duration=25ms)
```

***But this seems to be not supported in TypeScript function.***

**helloDurable.ts:**

```js
const activityName = 'durableHello';


const durableHelloOrchestrator: OrchestrationHandler = function* (context: OrchestrationContext) {
    const outputs = [];

    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Tokyo'));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Seattle'));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Cairo'));

    context.log('---------------context.isReplaying-------------', context.df.isReplaying);
    context.log('----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying---------------', context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying);
    context.log('*******************************');
    return outputs;
};
```

**Console Output:**

It's resulting as `Undefined`.

```js
C:\Users\username\nodedf>func host start

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-27T13:27:24.037Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        durableHelloHttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/{orchestratorName}     

        durableHello: activityTrigger

        durableHelloOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-27T13:27:28.898Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.   
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.068Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloHttpStart' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d8ba3616-aa6c-4ae9-85e9-ef0fa2f804f0)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.474Z] Started orchestration with ID = '7b691ed6a5c241d7baa89f7a897d252c'.
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.569Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloHttpStart' (Succeeded, Id=d8ba3616-aa6c-4ae9-85e9-ef0fa2f804f0, Duration=523ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.590Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=c859ecc1-aeef-49ec-bb18-11069eec72a0)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.619Z] ---------------context.df.isReplaying------------- undefined[2023-12-27T13:37:48.619Z] ----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying--------------- False

[2023-12-27T13:37:48.619Z] *******************************
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.652Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=c859ecc1-aeef-49ec-bb18-11069eec72a0, Duration=68ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.749Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=4b7d5bc9-2161-49d0-8184-e88e22f71417)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.760Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHello' (Succeeded, Id=4b7d5bc9-2161-49d0-8184-e88e22f71417, Duration=15ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.831Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=05216e65-39f8-4a0f-acb5-e91b1d471b7d)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.840Z] ---------------context.df.isReplaying------------- undefined
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.840Z] *******************************
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.840Z] ----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying--------------- True       
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.849Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=05216e65-39f8-4a0f-acb5-e91b1d471b7d, Duration=20ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.887Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=d0355ca2-ea72-4601-a428-bc7b5291f7ea)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.894Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHello' (Succeeded, Id=d0355ca2-ea72-4601-a428-bc7b5291f7ea, Duration=7ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.944Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=3b0d725f-d985-4777-ac3d-36ee798aac38)
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.955Z] ---------------context.df.isReplaying------------- undefined
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.956Z] *******************************
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.955Z] ----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying--------------- True       
[2023-12-27T13:37:48.958Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=3b0d725f-d985-4777-ac3d-36ee798aac38, Duration=14ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.024Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=41419c19-807a-4858-b96e-f824b2a3fc84)
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.031Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHello' (Succeeded, Id=41419c19-807a-4858-b96e-f824b2a3fc84, Duration=7ms)
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.104Z] Executing 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=6c78fa90-ebf7-4732-86c6-3ed0bc3c5a15)
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.124Z] ---------------context.df.isReplaying------------- undefined
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.125Z] *******************************
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.124Z] ----------------context.triggerMetadata.isReplaying--------------- True       
[2023-12-27T13:37:49.137Z] Executed 'Functions.durableHelloOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=6c78fa90-ebf7-4732-86c6-3ed0bc3c5a15, Duration=33ms)
```